# Display symbols/icons before and after textfield

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a requirement to display one symbol just before the textfield and at the end display .00, below is the code that i am using but do not get any idea how to do so.

```
                                  xtype:"textfield",    
                                  fieldLabel: 'Total Anticipated Mkt Val',
                                  labelStyle:'font-weight:bold;',
                                  name:"totalAnticipatedMarketValue",
                                  id: 'totalAnticipatedMarketValue',
                                  style:{color:'#0a4374',fontSize:'10px',fontWeight:'',textAlign:'left'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `fieldcontainer`, like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    fieldLabel: 'Total Anticipated Mkt Val',
    labelStyle:'font-weight:bold;',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            value: '$'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            name: "totalAnticipatedMarketValue",
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            value: '.00'
        }
    ]
}
```

See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer